# How to restart fvwm2 from the command line?

Tags: fvwm

For a very specific software application, we maintain a base of machines running fvwm 2.5. To update the menu structure, the fvwm2rc default config file is replaced during the update process performed by a package management system. To enable the new menu structure after an update, the user has to manually perform an action: Restart machine, re-login, restart fvwm. The preferred action is to choose "Window Manager > Restart Fvwm2" since no login is needed then and even the windows survive.

Question: How can I invoke an equivalent action as "Restart Fvwm2" from the command line or the package management system? The following command does not work (neither do similar ones):

```
fvwm -c "Restart"
[FVWM][SetupICCCM2]: <<ERROR>> another ICCCM 2.0 compliant WM is running, try -replace
```

"-replace" is no option since one needs to log in again after calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is either to make fvwm re-read the configuration or restart it completely. Additionally, I'm not totally sure that `-c` does what you want.

The fast or dirty way would be:

```
killall fvwm
fvwm
```

> Note: Please do not execute this on a BSD or Solaris system, as killall will kill the init process there. killall processname is Linux only.

But I'm not sure if this wouldn't destroy some window information (location, dimensions etc.). Or, you could try replacing the current session:

```
fvwm --replace
```

That should end the old fvwm process, launch a new one and even keep the windows correctly.

If fvwm is your x-session, you could still try to use [FvwmCommand](http://www.fvwm.org/documentation/manpages/unstable/FvwmCommand.php), the external command interface which seems to be able to send commands to the currently running fvwm.

Comment: Thanks Bobby, but as I already stated, 'replace' does not work for me since I have to login again after that command. Unfortunately, it is the same with 'killall fvwm'.

Comment: @Chris: Now I'm confused, why is fvwm running if there is no user logged in?

Comment: At the beginning I'm logged in, but the command 'fvwm -replace' logs me out, I have to log in again after calling it, the same thing happens with 'killall fvwm'.

Comment: "killing the previously running wm may terminate your X session, if the wm was started as the last client in your .Xclients or .Xsession file." -- This is expected behaviour when you restart your WM, you have to log in again. Some WM's offer a "reload" (like spectrwm), that keeps your windows and session. fvwm seems to lack this.

Comment: @Chris: I see, didn't think of that. See my edit.

Comment: @Bobby: Thanks a lot, your last edit contains the info I was looking for, the restart can be invoked with 'FvwmCommand Restart'. There is an imperfection though: To use FvwmCommand one has to spawn it first - with an entry in the very same fvwm2rc file :(  However, this "update recursion" is acceptable. Servus!

Answer (score 1):

[The Manual](http://www.fvwm.org/documentation/manpages/unstable/fvwm.php#Restart) tells us:

> Here are some cases when 'Restart fvwm2' or 'Restart fvwm' cause
>   troubles:
>
> - running fvwm under a session manager
> - running fvwm with multi headed displays
> - having command line arguments, like   -f themes-rc or -cmd
> - if the first fvwm2 in the $PATH is a   different one

These points hint to why you see that message, check each of them off in your case.

Define some keyboard shortcuts to enact the restart command (also in the manual):

```
Key F1 R N Restart
Key F1 R N Restart fvwm -s
Key F1 R N Restart ~/bin/fvwm -f $HOME/.fvwm/main
Key F1 R N Restart fvwm1 -s -f .fvwmrc
Key F1 R N Restart xterm -n '"X console"' \
  -T \"X\ console\" -e fvwm1 -s
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a misunderstanding... The restart works well if I select it from the fvwm menu, it is the behavior I want. But I want it from the command line, that is, from outside of fvwm itself.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. There are no `USR SIGNALS` defined for fvwm, to trigger external restart, so @Bobby's answer is good in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

`FvwmCommand` requires the `FvwmCommandS` FIFO to be open. If you cannot be sure all your users have one, it won't work.

But FVWM *will* restart on SIGUSR1.

An FVWM restart will even work if it is the last command in `.Xsession`.

But as other have said, if running under an X session manager (and FVWM has been compiled with session manager support), FVWM won't restart by itself, it will merely quit and expect to be restarted by the session manager. This will also affect SIGUSR1 behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [FvwmCommand](http://www.fvwm.org/documentation/manpages/unstable/FvwmCommand.php):

```
$ FvwmCommand Restart
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following works:

```
kill -SIGUSR1 pid
```

where pid is the process id of the fvwm process to restart; easier (on Linux):

```
killall -SIGUSR1 fvwm
```